# How to calculate weighted average cost for a business units when there is more than one weight parameters to account?

Tags: budgeting

Trying to solve how to allocate a cost (based on weight) to different units to justify cost distribution: Here is the problem.

There are certain cost known to a live stock firm and only know at grand total not at the unit level. e.g., electricity, or bank interest yearly of the firm. There are different batches(units) of flock with different quantity in number(parameter 1), and also there are difference in occupancy of the flock in the firm (parameter 2).

Example

- Batch 1 has 2000 qty, and lived in the firm for 12 months
- Batch 2 has 3000 qty, and lived in the firm for 06 months
- Batch 3 has 5000 qty, and lived in the firm for 02 months
  Assume the total cost of electricity in the year is 120,000 dollars.
  Then how do I segregate the 120k of cost to each units - Batch 1, batch 2 and batch 3?

Trying to solve as below, where we are multiplying each weight qty% and occupancy month %, and again determining the new weight out of that. Is it a correct approach to solve this, what else we can do to come with a right weight on this. Please suggest.

[image]